# Export chart data from PRPT report

Tags: pentaho

Is it possible to download data from single chart on PRPT report in Pentaho?

I'd like download csv format in my case.

I've searched urls like this:

http://localhost:8080/pentaho/api/repos/public%3Araporty%3AAuditLogsChartDouble.prpt/generatedContent?output-target=pageable%2Fpdf

but it's for a whole report. I didn't find any solution to export data from one chart.

Comment: URL is not accessible as it is localhost URL.
what do you mean by PRPT report?

Comment: It's just an example, that's why localhost. Main part is: 
pentaho/api/repos/public%3Araporty%3AAuditLogsChartDouble.prpt/generatedContent?output-target=pageable%2Fpdf

PRPT report, I mean report with prpt file extension.